# Ubuntu won't boot properly after deleting snap

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi, swap, tpm

I recently updated Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and it was working fine. Then, it decided to stop booting, it gets frozen in the logo screen. I notice this happen just after I uninstall snapd and it might related somehow to the loop devices. I don't know what else to do. Grub seems to be working fine. I tried to boot by editing the grub as this article said https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ by writing nomodeset in the grub menu and this message pop up

```
[0.595979] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[0.607978] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[0.615972] ima: Error communicating to TPM chip
[3.683385] systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap / swapfile.
```

I checked /etc/fstab and this was the output:

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>`
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/loop17 /mnt/loop17 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/loop20 /mnt/loop20 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e3570a2d-d4f2-4c0f-8725-44b4b50b4059 /mnt/e3570a2d-d4f2-4c0f-8725-44b4b50b4059 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I also make sure secure boot wasn't activated in my UEFI menu.

Comment: If you deleted all snaps, but are still mounting them in fstab, mount will fail & often boot fails. Have not seen them mounted with fstab. Where did those entries come from? Try turning tpm back on in UEFI settings. But leave UEFI Secure boot off. Did you also delete swap file as your fstab says that is what you are mounting? You could tempoarily comment it out with # to see if that is issue.

Comment: It seems that the option to modify TPM is not available in my UEFI settings. If there any other way to modify? I am using a Thinkpad T430. I got those entries from recovery mode shell. I think those loop devices used to belong to snap store and other program. I recently deleted and created other swap file but nothing happend.

Comment: Older system, so older versions of TPM, probably can ignore those errors. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Here is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WQDJ22DjPx/

Comment: You do not show / mounted. You have that partition mounted as a data partition by UUID.  Do you have a backup of fstab to make it easy to restore the root entry. Otherwise create a new / entry in your fstab. See example, but use your UUID & ext4. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: It worked. Thanks buddy :)